# The integers in the array are either entirely odd or entirely even except for a single integer

Tags: ruby

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least three, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this outlier N.

This is my code so far, which doesn't seem to work:

```
arr = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
n = arr.length

def getOddOccurrence(arr, arr_size)
  for i in range(0, arr_size)
    count = 0
    for j in range(0, arr_size)
      if arr[i] == arr[j]
        count += 1
      end
      if(count % 2 != 0)
        return arr[i]
      end
    end
  end
  return -1
end

print getOddOccurrence(arr, n)
```

What change do I need with this code?

Comment: `arr.first(3).count(&:odd?) > 1 ? arr.find(&:even?) : arr.find(&:odd?)`

Comment: Very pythonic! ;) Apart the answers you are going to receive, take a tour here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html

Comment: This looks like a challenge from hackerrank or similar sites. Is it?

Comment: @Sergio I wish you had kept your answer up because it gives a brief explanation as to what the code is doing and you also give the technical name of the process.

Comment: @SagarPandya: as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
arr = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
arr.group_by(&:odd?).values.sort_by(&:count)[0][0]
# => 160
```

`group_by(&:odd?)` Will make 2 hashes for odd and even numbers

`values` Will grab the values of the hash. 2 arrays, for even and odd

`sort_by(&:count)` Sort arrays, one with less values will be first

`[0][0]` Grab the first number of the first array

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that is arcane (ugly), but relatively straightforward. It takes O(`arr.size`) time and uses O(1) additional storage.  It also "short-circuits" as soon as it finds the outlier.

Here's the basic idea.  Even numbers have zero for the least significant bit, and odd numbers have one, so if you XOR an adjacent pair of numbers the least significant bit will be one only if they lack parity.  The first time that happens after the first pair, you've found the outlier.  If it happens with the first pair, you need to check the second pairing. If that yields a zero, the first value was the outlier, otherwise it was the second.

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr)
  arr.each_index do |i|
    return arr[i == 1 && (arr[i] ^ arr[i + 1]) & 1 == 0 ? 0 : i] if i > 0 && (arr[i] ^ arr[i - 1]) & 1 == 1
  end
end
```

And here's the same concept in a slightly more Rubyish manner:

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr)
  arr.each_cons(3) { |x,y,z| return ((y ^ z) & 1 == 1 ? y : x) if (x ^ y) & 1 == 1 }
  arr[-1]
end
```

If you prefer looking at subsets of 2, make a one-off check of the first 3 values and then work with `cons(2)` subsets.  You can also replace bit-testing with a check for consistency on evenness (or oddness) to improve readability:

```
def getOddOccurrence(arr)
  return arr[0] if (arr[0].odd? ^ arr[1].odd?) && !(arr[1].odd? ^ arr[2].odd?)
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x,y| return y if (x.odd? ^ y.odd?)}
end
```

---

I finally had a few spare minutes to throw together a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def getOddOccurrence_cons3(arr)
  arr.each_cons(3) { |x,y,z| return ((y ^ z) & 1 == 1 ? y : x) if (x ^ y) & 1 == 1 }
  arr[-1]
end

def getOddOccurrence_cons2(arr)
  return arr[0] if (arr[0].odd? ^ arr[1].odd?) && !(arr[1].odd? ^ arr[2].odd?)
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x,y| return y if (x.odd? ^ y.odd?) }
end

def getOddOccurrence_cons2_bits(arr)
  return arr[0] if ((arr[0] ^ arr[1]) & 1 == 1) && ((arr[1] ^ arr[2]) & 1 == 0)
  arr.each_cons(2) { |x,y| return y if (x ^ y) & 1 == 1 }
end

def getOddOccurrence_find(arr)
  arr.first(3).count(&:odd?) > 1 ? arr.find(&:even?) : arr.find(&:odd?)
end

def getOddOccurrence_find_bits(arr)
  arr.first(3).sum {|x| x & 1} > 1 ? arr.find { |x| (x & 1) == 0 } : arr.find { |x| (x & 1) == 1 }
end

def find_outlier(ary)
  # fetch first 3 numbers and determine what kind of array
  # are we dealing with here, mostly odd or mostly even?
  mostly_odd = ary.take(3).count(&:odd?) > 1

  # then just go and find the outlier element
  if mostly_odd
    ary.find(&:even?)
  else
    ary.find(&:odd?)
  end
end

arr = Array.new(10_000) { |i| i * 2 }.shuffle << 5

Benchmark.ips do |b|
  b.report('cons3 bits:') { getOddOccurrence_cons3(arr) }
  b.report('cons2 bits:') { getOddOccurrence_cons2_bits(arr) }
  b.report('cons2 even/odd:') { getOddOccurrence_cons2(arr) }
  b.report('find even/odd:') { getOddOccurrence_find(arr) }
  b.report('find bits:') { getOddOccurrence_find_bits(arr) }
  b.report('find sergio:') { find_outlier(arr) }
  b.compare!
end
```

As you can see, I put an odd value at the end of an even array to maximize the searching required.

And the winner is...

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
         cons3 bits:   128.000  i/100ms
         cons2 bits:   127.000  i/100ms
     cons2 even/odd:   103.000  i/100ms
      find even/odd:   216.000  i/100ms
          find bits:   217.000  i/100ms
        find sergio:   231.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
         cons3 bits:      1.251k (± 4.9%) i/s -      6.272k in   5.026355s
         cons2 bits:      1.294k (± 3.4%) i/s -      6.477k in   5.010802s
     cons2 even/odd:      1.038k (± 4.4%) i/s -      5.253k in   5.070617s
      find even/odd:      2.284k (± 4.2%) i/s -     11.448k in   5.022831s
          find bits:      2.165k (± 5.3%) i/s -     10.850k in   5.027801s
        find sergio:      2.277k (± 3.3%) i/s -     11.550k in   5.078381s

Comparison:
      find even/odd::     2283.6 i/s
        find sergio::     2276.9 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
          find bits::     2164.6 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
         cons2 bits::     1294.2 i/s - 1.76x  slower
         cons3 bits::     1251.1 i/s - 1.83x  slower
     cons2 even/odd::     1038.1 i/s - 2.20x  slower
```

...the one-liner from Sagar Pandyar's comment!

The `find`-based approach clearly beats `each_cons`.  Using Ruby's `odd`/`even` methods vs binary operations appears to have only a minor impact.  Interestingly, using `.each_cons(3)` rather than `.each_cons(2)` has very little relative impact as well, although both are clearly dominated by Sagar & Sergio's approach.

Comment: Isn't `each_cons(3)` a bit wasteful after first two pairs are evaluated? Every pair except the first and the last will be checked twice.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right that it adds more work, but in the form of a scalar constant so it doesn't change the big-O behavior.  I've gone ahead and added a `cons(2)` version based on your comment.  One of these days I'll have to run some timings to see if it makes a noticeable difference.

Comment: Hm, I thought performance difference would be more pronounced. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linear-time constant-memory algorithm

```
def find_outlier(ary)
  # fetch first 3 numbers and determine what kind of array
  # are we dealing with here, mostly odd or mostly even?
  mostly_odd = ary.take(3).count(&:odd?) > 1

  # then just go and find the outlier element
  if mostly_odd
    ary.find(&:even?)
  else
    ary.find(&:odd?)
  end
end

ary = [161, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 160, 13, -21]

find_outlier(ary) # => 160
```